# Analysing threads through eclipse debug view

Tags: java, eclipse, performance

If a multi threaded application is running in debug from eclipse then is there any way to know which thread is sleeping or waiting by looking into debug view where all the threads are listed? As I can only see running threads there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the threads are shown, the `(Running)` value just means you have not suspended the thread. You can use the `Suspend` button to suspend an individual thread or the entire application. When you do this you can expand the entry for the thread in the view and see if it is sleeping, waiting or executing code.

Single suspended thread which is waiting:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use JvisualVM to get a graph over time of which threads are running/sleeping.  JvisualVM comes with your JDK.  If you are looking for a performance issue, it also has a profiler.  There is also a plugin for eclipse (which I've never used) that can help with launching it.  http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html