# How to debug multi threaded java program

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I have program and I have set some debug point in it,but when control reached to the `wait` method in side the `printEven` method, control goes to till wait method and become hidden and nothing happened. Can any one explain how to debug wait. Control goes to wait method and never return.I am using eclipse to debug it.

```
public class PrintEvenOddTester 
    {
        public static void main(String ... args)
        {
            Printer print = new Printer();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new TaskEvenOdd(print, 10,  false));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new TaskEvenOdd(print, 10, true));
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
    }
    class TaskEvenOdd implements Runnable 
    {
        private int max;
        private Printer print;
        private boolean isEvenNumber;
        TaskEvenOdd(Printer print, int max, boolean isEvenNumber)
        {
            this.print = print;
            this.max = max;
            this.isEvenNumber = isEvenNumber;
        }
        public void run() 
        {
            //System.out.println("Run method");
            int number = isEvenNumber == true ? 2 : 1;
            while(number<= max)
            {
                if(isEvenNumber)
                {
                    //System.out.println("Even :"+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    print.printEven(number);
                    // number+=2;
                }   
                else 
                {
                    //System.out.println("Odd :"+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    print.printOdd(number);
                  // number+=2;
                }
                number+=2;
            }
        }
    }

    class Printer 
    {
        boolean isOdd= false;
        synchronized void printEven(int number) 
        {
            while(isOdd == false)
            {
                try 
                {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Even:"+number);
            isOdd = false;
            notifyAll();
        }
        synchronized void printOdd(int number) 
        {
            while(isOdd == true)
            {
                try 
                {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Odd:"+number);
            isOdd = true;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176954/analysing-threads-through-eclipse-debug-view)

Comment: `wait` is a `native` method which you can’t step into. It will return if an appropriate `notify` has been encountered and the lock has been reacquired. While a thread is in a wait state it will not execute any code hence there is nothing to debug then.

Comment: Thanks Holger and DawnKeeper